# Minimize $ab+bc+ca$ under three second degree constraints

Tags: functions, optimization

As stated in the title, my problem is quite simple.

Minimize $ab+bc+ca$ under these three constraints:

$$
a^2+b^2=1
$$$$
b^2+c^2=2
$$$$
c^2+a^2=2
$$

I can brute force it, with some intelligence of course, and calculate the value of only three possibilities. But is there any way to do it with even more intelligence?

Answer (score 1):

First step is that you can get the possible values of $a,b,c$ according to 
$$
a^2+b^2=1
$$$$
b^2+c^2=2
$$$$
c^2+a^2=2
$$
Which are 
$$
a=\pm\sqrt{1/2}
$$$$
b=\pm\sqrt{1/2}
$$$$
c=\pm\sqrt{3/2}
$$
Notice that among the three products, $ab, bc$, and $ca$, at most 2 of them are negative, because at least 2 numbers among $a,b$ and $c$ have the same sign (i.e., these 2 numbers are either both negative, or positive). So if we can maximize the absolute values of these 2 negative products, we get the minimum value of $ab+bc+ca$. Which will be
$$
a=\sqrt{1/2}
$$$$
b=\sqrt{1/2}
$$$$
c=-\sqrt{3/2}
$$
and under this condition,
$$
ab+bc+ca=1/2-\sqrt{3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
With the constraints:
$$
b^{2} - c^{2}
=
\overbrace{\pars{a^{2} + b^{2}}}^{=\ 1}\ -\ \overbrace{\pars{c^{2} + a^{2}}}^{=\ 2}
=
-1
$$

$$
b^{2}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\bracks{\overbrace{\pars{b^{2} + c^{2}}}^{=\ 2}\
+\
\overbrace{\pars{b^{2} - c^{2}}}^{=\ -1}}
=
{1 \over 2}
$$

$$
a^{2} = 1 - b^{2} = {1 \over 2}\,,
\qquad\qquad
c^{2} = 2 - b^{2} = {3 \over 2}
$$

Then,
$$
a_{\pm} = \pm\,{\sqrt{2\,} \over 2}\,,
\qquad
b_{\pm} = \pm\,{\sqrt{2\,} \over 2}
\,,
\qquad
c_{\pm} = \pm\,{\sqrt{6\,} \over 2}
$$